# Apply function on list of tables in database

Tags: r

I was wondering how I could automate a treatment on a list of tables stored in a database.

Here is my failed attempt:

```
#Listing and storing database tables in a list :

db_tbls <- dbListTables(pool)   
tbl_list <- lapply(db_tbls, dbReadTable, conn = pool)
tbl_list <- setNames(tbl_list, db_tbls)

function_beta <- function(table){

#1. converting "year" column into integer
tbl_list$table$year<- as.integer(tbl_list$table$year)

#2. transposing table
table_ok<- transpose(tbl_list$table)

#3. Adding rownames based on colnames and replacing old colnames by the year column values
rownames(table_ok) <- colnames(tbl_list$table)
colnames(table_ok) <- unlist(table_ok[row.names(table_ok)=='year',])
table_ok<- table_ok[!row.names(table_ok)=='year',]

#4 Extract dataframes from list and rename them
???

}

lapply(tbl_list, function_beta)
```

Could someone help me out please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually came up with this solution:

```
db_tbls <- dbListTables(pool)   
tbl_list <- lapply(db_tbls, dbReadTable, conn = pool)
tbl_list <- setNames(tbl_list, db_tbls)

pimped_tables =list()


  for (i in 1:length(tbl_list)) {
    
    #1. converting "year" column into integer
    tbl_list[[i]]$year<- as.integer(tbl_list[[i]]$year)
  
    #2. transposing table
    pimped_tables[[i]] <- transpose(tbl_list[[i]])
    
    #3. Adding rownames based on colnames and replacing old colnames by the year column values
    rownames(pimped_tables[[i]]) <- colnames(tbl_list[[i]])
    colnames(pimped_tables[[i]]) <- unlist(pimped_tables[[i]][row.names(pimped_tables[[i]])=='year',])
    pimped_tables[[i]]<- pimped_tables[[i]][!row.names(pimped_tables[[i]])=='year',]
    
    rownames(pimped_tables[[i]]) <- gsub("X","",rownames(pimped_tables[[i]]))


    print(pimped_tables)[[i]]

    
    }
```